# Ubuntu won't start after update

Tags: data-recovery

My Ubuntu freeze during the upgrade of 15 to 16, now he does not want to start again. after the loading screen it stops at a black screen and does nothing. I tried this tutorial http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2217829 replacing RO for RW but it stop in other black screen.

Can someone help me to at least recover my files?

Comment: Honestly, if the upgrade was interrupted, your best bet is to reinstall.

Comment: **What kind of graphics card do you have? Nvidia? Is it a hybrid graphics card?**   -  

*(Question via **[JOnathanJOnes](https://askubuntu.com/users/505240/jonathanjones))***

Answer (score 1):

#### Do you hear the login dialog sound while the black screen?

- **If yes:**

  - There is a problem with the graphics driver.
- **If not:**

  - *Can someone help me to at least recover my files?*
    If the upgrade froze the files in your home directory should not be
    touched.

#### So a way could be:

**First:**
Restart the installation process **(you should backup your home directory before the reinstallation).**

**Second:**
Check if all your files in the home directory are still there.
If not, Restore your files from the backup you made in the last step.

Comment: I can backup this directory in text mode?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, that should backup your home directory: tar -cvpzf backup.tar.gz --exclude=/backup.tar.gz --one-file-system /home/your-name. After creating the backup file you should copy it onto a save place like a usb stick.